# What does the message "Test Movie Launch Failed" mean? (Flash Professional CC)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air

**The Problem**

When I was creating a test program using Flash Professional CC, I got the message "Test Movie Launch Failed" while compiling, and when I tried to open it, nothing happened and it didn't open.  However, I got no compiler errors whatsoever, it just said "Test Movie Terminated." in the output.

**What Might be Going on**

I was thinking it might have been an error in my code, but I can't tell since the error message is extremely vague and no runtime errors appear.

So Here's my code (just in case if it's an error of the code)

### Info:

Target: Air 3.6 for Desktop

Script: ActionScript 3.0

Objects:

Input Text Box with instance name of "writeT"

Dynamic Text Box with instance name of "readT"

MovieClip with instance name of "Write" (Too lazy to make buttons)

MovieClip with instance name of "Read"

---

```
import flash.filesystem.*;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

Write.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, writeToFile);
Read.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, readFile);

var file:File = File.desktopDirectory.resolvePath("stuff.txt");
var fs:FileStream = new FileStream();

function writeToFile(e:MouseEvent):void{
    fs.open(file, FileMode.APPEND);
    var text:String = writeT.text;
    fs.writeUTF(text);
    writeT.text = "";
    fs.close();
}

function readFile(e:MouseEvent):void{
    fs.open(file, FileMode.READ);
    var text:String = fs.readUTF();
    readT.text = text;
    fs.close();
}
```

EDIT: I commented all of my code and the error still showed up, so ignore the code

Comment: You might not have a Flash debugger version and the connection to the debugger fails for that reason (obviously) and the debug test is terminated.

Answer (score 1):

I typically see this if I use a library (.swc or .ane) that the desktop debugger cannot use.

If you using any libraries, perhaps uncouple them to see if the error disappears.

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to say what the exact problem could be. From what I read, seems like a version issue. This thread maybe of some help : https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1007928

On a side note, I noticed that you have your instance named as **Write** and **Read**. I would typically avoid such names as they might conflict with reserved keywords, and while naming instances, it's best to name them using a camel case convention.

So, I would name them something Iike **writeMc** and **readMc**.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

if you're publishing a mobile app, test on a mobile.  you will get that error when using certain mobile-only code in the test environment.  ie, test on an appropriate (ios/android) mobile.